# passing value when you press button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am having trouble passing a value
[when pressing this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAjsC.png)(the code for the button down below).

```
<div class="timeline-footer">
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="onderreact_btn" type="submit">Reageer</button>
</div>
```

It needs to give a `<form>` a id from that reaction.

the code for the form to save it in the db. this works just fine but now it needs to give the id from the reaction when pressing the button to this form.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){
    unset($q1);
    $q1['reactie'] = $app->check_string($_POST['reactie']);
    $q1['topic_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['topicid']);
    $q1['klant_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['klantid']);
    $q1['ledenpagina_id'] = $app->check_string($_POST['ledenpaginaid']);
    $app->insert_query('reacties', $q1, 'id');
  }  

?>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Reactie:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="reactie" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
      <input type="hidden" name="klantid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["klant_id"] ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="topicid" value="<?php echo $actieftopicid ?>"
      <input type="hidden" name="ledenpaginaid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["ledenpagina_id"]; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="onderreactieID" value="<?php echo $reactie; ?>">
      <button type="submit" name="react_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Plaats reactie</button>
     </div>              
   </form>
```

I think I need to make a `hidden` input where I post the reactionID in and make some kind of javascript variable with a default set to 0 and when pressing on a button it needs to give that value trough to this variable

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a test, if the button was pressed, check if the button was submittd:

```
if (isset($_POST['react_btn')) {
    // ...
}
```

But as the value of the button is it's text, you should also add an hidden field, storing your id.

Keep in mind, that you could also submit the form by pressing enter inside a textfield in the form - in this case, the button wasn't pressed!